# Not able to disable scrolling in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a `SingleChildScrollView` and when tapping on `FormTextField` in it, the keyboard appears and the scroll view is scrolled upwards. After dismissing the keyboard, I am still able to scroll the Scrollview manually. Can you please suggest any solution to disable the manual scrolling after `FormTextField` disappears.

Answer (score 48):

You can use the following code in your singleChildScrollView.

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

It stops it from being able to scroll.

Comment: I'm still able to scoll. Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when I put `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` `SingleChildScrollView` can't be scrolled, but a scroll bar appears. If I use the scroll bar, the content is scrolled.

I need to hide the scroll bar:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
    behavior:
        ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: child,
    )),
```

Answer (score -2):

I think we have the same problem. I use two settings in singleChildScrollView

physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
reverse: true,

This solution is acceptable to me, I hope it is good for you.